# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'maxlong' was corrupted

Tags: stack, corruption

I wrote a code to print the length of the longest line from my input and print out as much as possible of the longest line(There is a  maximum length of what I can output the longest line). But I got this error. I tried everything I could yet still no clue. Is there anyone who might help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 10
int getline(char line[], int len) {
    int i,c,max;
    i = 0;
    max = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF&&c!='\n') {
        if (i < len) {
            line[i] = c;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    if (i < len) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            line[i] = c;
            i += 1;
        }
        line[i] = '\0';
    }
    else if (i >= len) {
        line[len] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}
void copy(char from[], char to[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (from[i] != '\0') {
        to[i] = from[i];
        i += 1;
    }
    to[i] = '\0';
}

main() {
    char longline[MAXLINE];
    char longestline[MAXLINE];
    char maxlong[MAXLINE];
    int length;
    int max = 0;
    int maxline = 0;
    while ((length = getline(longline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (length > max && length < MAXLINE) {
            copy(longline, longestline);
            max = length;
        }
        else if (length > MAXLINE) {
            if (length > maxline) {
                maxline = length;
                copy(longline, maxlong);
            }
        }
    }
    if (maxline == 0) {
        printf("%s", longestline);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s\n%d\n", maxlong, maxline);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow, For your help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey. Thank you. I saw what others asked but it is difficult for me to understand. So could you please help me with this problem?